# Getting mapped custom domain url in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My azure web application (myapp.azurewebsites.net) is mapped to a custom domain (client1.mycompany.com).

I will be mapping it to some more custom domains (client2.mycompany.com, client3.mycompany.com etc.) one per each client.

In web application I am using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

to get custom domain address which is accessing the application. But it is sometimes returning myapp.azurewebsites.net instead of custom domain.

Any idea how I can custom domain url in Azure in reliable way?

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900883/get-azure-webapp-website-name-at-runtime.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Gaurav, I tried to get "HTTP_DISGUISED_HOST", "HTTP_HOST" from ConfigurationManager, but it failed.

Comment: Adding on to @Ruslany's answer, the reason the hostname request returns myapp.azurewebsites.net is because the user navigated to myapp.azurewebsites.net in their web browser. Basically HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host returns whatever url the customer put in the address bar.  Ruslany's answer provides a way to redirect all users who try to visit myapp.azurewebsites.net to a custom domain of your choice

Answer (score 1):

As Admir said in his answer the default *.azurewebsites.net binding cannot be removed, but it is very easy to prevent users from using this domain name for your site.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="client1.mycompany.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://client1.mycompany.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: That's a good solution in general, but in this case how do you know which client domain to redirect to?  I think this is what @Admir meant by a "default custom domain".

Answer (score 0):

*.azurewebsites.net is not removable which means it is out of your control if someone will access your website through that DNS binding, which explains why you get that when you attempt to inspect HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.

Only thing you can do is to choose to ignore requests coming directly to that binding, by redirecting user to:

- Custom page (i.e. 404)
- Some default custom domain