# MS azure remove default domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created web app named `XYZ` in MS Azure. It automatically created domain XYZ.azurewebsites.net. Then I bought and added a custom domain. The problem now is the `XYZ.azurewebsites.net` still shows what has been deployed to my domain `MYDOMAIN.COM`. How can I remove the default domain?

Comment: What do you mean, "remove the default domain?"

Comment: Well, when I go to XYZ.azurewebsites.net it shows my website deployed to MYDOMAIN.COM. That is obviously wrong, so I would like to remove the dns record for XYZ.azurewebsites.net. I can manage DNS records for MYDOMAIN.com but cannot find where to access the ones for XYZ.azurewebsites.net :-) Thanks. Petr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting mapped custom domain url in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914361/getting-mapped-custom-domain-url-in-azure)

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove Azure's DNS record - that is how everything for your web app is controlled/managed in Azure. You can add no-index and no-follow options for search engines and add a permanent redirect in your app from the Azure DNS to yours.

Comment: Really? So you are saying that EVERY web app hosted on Azure has somewhere a mirror like this? What about web bots which dont respect meta tags and index it anyway?
Anyway, the point is I cannot add no-index, no-follow options nor I can add permanent redirect for this site as this the some site as MYDOMAIN.com. I simply deployed the app and it shows on XYZ.azurewebsites.net :-(
Or maybe it's possible, could you point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so after some googling, I found out this is a common problem with using Azure (shame MS doesnt makes life easier here).
I solved it by using permanent redirect in web.config from this thread
[Getting mapped custom domain url in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914361/getting-mapped-custom-domain-url-in-azure)
Thank you for taking interest
Petr

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Web Application Gateway with my Azure App service and I found the below option of 'Access Restrictions' after that it stopped all the traffic on my default DNS link of https://SAMPLE.azurewebsites.net
Here is the way to look for 'Access Restrictions'
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added two rules to my `web.config` file. The first was a rule to perform a permanent redirect from the default domain to the custom domain. You can also throw a forbidden error message with HTTP status code 403. The second rule was an outbound rule to block search engine requests to the default domain.

```
<system.webserver>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^old-domain.azurewebsites.net$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://new-domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Noindex Domains">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag" pattern=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^old-domain.azurewebsites.net$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If your site is verified with Google under its Search Console, you can also temporarily remove a URL from search results; it lasts 6 months. Go to Removals, click the "New Request" button and then use a URL prefix as the option for blocking indexing; it will block all requests beginning with the URL instead of the root URL only. This request can take a little while to process. You can also submit a Change of Address request to let Google know you have changed site URLs by going to Settings > Change of address, where you can specify the old domain and new/moved domain.